# Type casting mismatch issue in file.WriteAllLines

Tags: c#, database, string-concatenation

Scenario is read data from DB and append 2 string and pass into file.WriteAllLine method

I want to concatenate `string connecString + dc[j] + "INQ;"` as I have take these in `list<string>` but getting error. 
and file.WriteAllLines method only accept the string array not accept simple array. 
Thanks in advance

**My code**

```
public void ComapnySelection_FromDB(string conncString) {

  try {

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------- -------------------- ");

    String que = "select ConsumerNo from " + conncString + "";
    List < string > dc = ConnectToData(que);
    Console.WriteLine("ConsumerNo in DB: " + dc[0]);
    for (int j = 0; j < dc.Count; j++) {
      List<string> combine = conncString + dc[j] + "INQ;";
      Console.WriteLine("Module Name from DB: " + dc[j]);
      File.WriteAllLines(path, dc);

    }
  } catch (Exception) {
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR!");

  }

}
```

Comment: Your posted code makes very little sense. What error do you get BTW?

Comment: i'm getting error in type casting like i want to pass a concatenated string in File.WriteAllLines 
e.g. in above code two variables are used connString and dc[j]. and third i want append "INQ;" string 
after that i want to concatenate these 3 like List < string > combine = conncString + dc[j] + "INQ;"; 
and pass through File.WriteAllLines(path combani);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [File.WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
for (int j = 0; j < dc.Count; j++) {
  var combine = conncString + dc[j] + "INQ;";
  Console.WriteLine("Module Name from DB: " + dc[j]);
  File.WriteAllText(path, combine);

}
```

Comment: but it's just print only one record not whole records at a time.

Comment: @NeelGurbani use AppendText

Comment: what i want to everytime file clean in case of append will be fail :)

Comment: @NeelGurbani so, I don't understand, why my first solution is incorrect

Comment: when i'm using append instead of writealltext. what it's do it's write again and again not override the content 
e.g. 
if i run program with WriteAlltext it will overwrite the same content
and if i run the program with AppenAllTextr it will append the same content
still not getting read this from MSDN:
Write all text: Creates a new file, writes the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.
Append All Text: Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, ......